# Locator and manipulate

Tags: graphics, manipulate, locator

How can I achieve that the points on a Graphics element could be manipulated both by Locators (clicking and moving) and on the Manipulate panel as well.

As you can see, only one of the methods work. In this example only `pt1` appears on the Manipulate panel.

So any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
Manipulate[
    Graphics[{Polygon[{pt1, pt2, pt3}]}, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}],

 {{pt1, {0, 0}}}, {{pt2, {0, 1}}, Locator}, {{pt3, {1, 1}}, Locator}]
```

[image: loc1]

Comment: I missed the Locator statement to show that if I miss it, pt1 appears in the manipulate bar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can attach multiple controls to a variable:

```
Manipulate[Graphics[{Polygon[{pt1, pt2, pt3}]}, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
  Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}], 
 {{pt1, {0, 0}}}, {{pt2, {0,  1}}}, {{pt3, {1, 1}}},
 Row[{Control@{{pt1, {0, 0}}, {0, 0}, {10, 10}, Slider2D}, 
   Control@{{pt2, {0, 1}}, {0, 0}, {10, 10}, Slider2D}, 
   Control@{{pt3, {1, 1}}, {0, 0}, {10, 10}, Slider2D}}, Spacer[5]],
 {{pt1, {0, 0}}, Locator}, {{pt2, {0, 1}}, Locator}, {{pt3, {1, 1}}, Locator}]
```

[image]

Comment: Recommend that you add `Appearance -> "Labeled"` to each `Slider2D`.

Comment: @BobHanlon, from your comment, I gather `Slider2D` _finally_  got the `Appearance` option in Version 10. In version 9, the option `Appearance`  is not supported. I am using the free cloud version of Version 10, where  neither `Locator`  nor `Slider2D` works. I would be curious to see the how the `Labeled` Slider2D` looks/works.

Comment: demonstrated in my "extended comment"

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer but rather an extended comment to @kguler to demonstrate `Appearance -> "Labeled"` with `Slider2D` in version 10.1

```
$Version
```

> "10.1.0  for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)"

Using @kguler answer

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Polygon[{pt1, pt2, pt3}]},
  PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  Frame -> True,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}}],
 {{pt1, {0, 0}}},
 {{pt2, {0, 1}}},
 {{pt3, {1, 1}}},
 Row[{
   Control@{{pt1, {0, 0}}, {0, 0}, {10, 10},
     Slider2D, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
   Control@{{pt2, {0, 1}}, {0, 0}, {10, 10},
     Slider2D, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
   Control@{{pt3, {1, 1}}, {0, 0}, {10, 10},
     Slider2D, Appearance -> "Labeled"}},
  Spacer[5]],
 {{pt1, {0, 0}}, Locator},
 {{pt2, {0, 1}}, Locator},
 {{pt3, {1, 1}}, Locator}]
```

[image]